# foreach loop loops once on empty array, bug?

Tags: php, foreach

I've found weird behaviour in PHPs foreach loop. When I do it like this:

```
<?php
$arr = array();

foreach ( $arr as $a )
{
    echo 'Hello';
}
?>
```

Then as I expect, nothing is printed simply because the array is empty, but when I do it like this:

```
<? $arr = array(); ?>

<? foreach ( $arr as $a ): ?>
    Hello
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Then the word 'Hello' is printed once... Even though the array is empty. I don't see why this would behave differently. To me this looks like a bug, but I could be missing something...

I'm using PHP 5.4 (Windows).

And in case you're wondering, I'm using the second method in my .phtml files (template files).

Comment: Do you have PHP short tags enabled?  Maybe it's showing "Hello" because the PHP isn't running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some tests, and it seems this is happening because `short_open_tag` is off.

You're seeing "Hello" because the PHP is not being ran.

You need to edit your `php.ini` and set `short_open_tag` to `1`.

As of PHP 5.4, the `<?php echo` alias `<?=` is always available, but the short tag (`<?`) syntax still needs that option set.

Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I thought because <?= ?> did work, that short tags were enabled. But they weren't and it's working now. I'll accept your answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: @w00: Yeah in PHP 5.4 `<?=` is enabled regardless of the `short_open_tag` option.

Comment: I do not think short_open_tag is the problem. Try the following example:


     `$items = '';
     foreach((array)$items as $item){
      echo  $item . '  xxx ';
     }`

It prints "xxx" even when the $items variable is empty

Comment: @Shouvik: `short_open_tag` was the solution to this problem.  His PHP code wasn't being ran, so the page just output `"Hello"`. The code you posted is ***completely*** different.  Your code works because `(array)$items` is the same as doing `array($items)`.  You wind up with an array with one element, so the loop runs and prints `'xxx'`.  Docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting